# From an array, find the array that has the true values for the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given array:
const array = [{1: true},{2: false},{3: true},{}.....];

Filter the given array by only including objects with values of true.

Looking for the shortest solution.

Comment: Why don't you add the solution you've come up with first? That might be the shortest solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
const onlyTrue = array.filter((el, ind) => el[ind + 1] === true);
```

This will work only if indexes in array objects are ordered and starting from 1, as it is in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions (based on what's in your example):

- Each object in the array only has at least 1 property in it
- The first property on each object is the one we care about
- The property in each object is different every time

```js
const array = [{1: true},{2: false},{3: true}];
const results = array.filter(item => Object.values(item)[0]);
```

If you want to avoid any false positives from truth-y values (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then change the filter call to this instead:

```js
const results = array.filter(item => Object.values(item)[0] === true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [{1: true},{2: false},{3: true}];
const array2 = [];
array.forEach(filterTrue);
function filterTrue(item){
    for(x in item){
        if(item[x]===true){
            array2.push(item);
        }
    }
}
console.log(array2);

Hope this helps you.
```